# extract data with minimum time difference between each 2 samples

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with samples timestamp:

```
create table #OREN_TEMP(TS datetime)

insert into #OREN_TEMP(TS)
    values 
    ('2019-10-25 06:20:07.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:20:15.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:20:19.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:20:26.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:20:26.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:20:34.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:20:42.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:20:51.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:20:59.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:21:07.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:21:15.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:21:19.000'),
    ('2019-10-25 06:21:26.000')

    select * from #OREN_TEMP
```

I've been asked to extract data from the table when minimum time between one sample to another is 20 seconds.
Meaning I need to extract the following:

```
('2019-10-25 06:20:07.000')
('2019-10-25 06:20:34.000')
('2019-10-25 06:20:59.000')
('2019-10-25 06:21:19.000')
```

I tried to do the following:

```
declare @MIN_DATE datetime

select top 1 @MIN_DATE =TS from #OREN_TEMP
order by TS
select TS
from (select TS, row_number() over (partition by datediff(second,@MIN_DATE,TS) / 20 order by TS) as RowNum
      from #OREN_TEMP
    ) TMP
where TMP.ROWNUM=1
```

and I got:

```
TS
2019-10-25 06:20:07.000
2019-10-25 06:20:34.000
2019-10-25 06:20:51.000 -- Not good - only 17 seconds from previous
2019-10-25 06:21:07.000 -- Not good - only 16 seconds from previous
```

but this didn't help as I divided the time frames based on the first TS and not from the last one.

I want to avoid loops nor cursor. Inner join with the table itself is OK.

How should I do it?
I'm using SQL server 2012 standard edition.

Comment: Have you had a look at `LEAD` or `LAG`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE for this.  But it is not efficient in SQL Server.  SQL Server has a number of restrictions on recursive CTEs, including no aggregation and no recursive references in subqueries.

So, here is one version:

```
with first_row as (
      select top (1) ot.*
      from oren_temp ot
      order by ts asc
     ),
     cte as (
      select ts, 1 as lev
      from first_row
      union all
      select ot.ts, lev + 1
      from oren_temp ot join
           cte
           on ot.ts >= dateadd(second, 20, cte.ts)
     )
select lev, min(ts)
from cte
group by lev;
```

[And a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=01e24aec1228522f1af7b6beddda18c0).

I would caution you from running this on datasets with too many rows, though.

EDIT:

Actually, there is a more efficient method.  At each recursive step, we can keep the previous first found `ts` (which is the minimum) using `row_number()`:

```
with first_row as (
      select top (1) ot.*
      from oren_temp ot
      order by ts asc
     ),
     cte as (
      select ts, 1 as lev, convert(int, 1) as seqnum
      from first_row
      union all
      select ot.ts, lev + 1, convert(int, row_number() over (partition by lev order by ot.ts)) as seqnum
      from oren_temp ot join
           cte
           on ot.ts >= dateadd(second, 20, cte.ts)
       where seqnum = 1
     )
select lev, ts, seqnum
from cte
where seqnum = 1;
```

This should be more efficient on larger data.  And, it is pretty cool too.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It is working !!!
Can you please explain me why we need "where seqnum = 1" inside the recursion and outside the recursion?
Brief explain on the code will be more than welcome.

Comment: @oren . . . Actually, I thought I did.  At each step in the recursion, many rows come on or after the 20 second limit.  The `seqnum = 1` does the filtering in the *next* round of recursion s only the first row is considered.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is like @Gordon, but made independently...

Again I used cte

```
;with cte as ( 
-- got first row , mark it RowNumber = 1
select top 1 ts, RN = 1 
from #OREN_TEMP

union all
-- in recursive part set number for all rows
select  T.ts, convert(int,row_number() over ( order by T.TS)) 
from #OREN_TEMP T 
-- join only to rows which are after 20+ secs
join cte T1 on datediff(SECOND,T1.TS, T.TS) >= 20
-- and we have to take RowNumber = 1 from cte
and T1.RN = 1
)
-- and result goes.......
select TS from cte
where RN = 1
```

Result

```
ts
-----------------------
2019-10-25 06:20:07.000
2019-10-25 06:20:34.000
2019-10-25 06:20:59.000
2019-10-25 06:21:19.000
```

EDIT

For countries like my (Russia) to run your inserts we have to prepend code with command

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy
```